# Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.WebPermission error only for sandboxed solutions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-services, sandbox-solution, exception

I have created a farm solutions to access external webservice an created a webpart. After deployed the solution it works fine.
Then requirement has been changed. So I changed the application to sandboxed, it endsup with error. I debug the code and it returns an exception.

> Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.WebPermission, System,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed. This is my code where exception was thrown.

```
 WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(@"https://URL");
```

In my sharepoint site I find the below error in webpart.

> Web Part Error: Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code
>   wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An
>   unexpected error has occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sandbox is an isolated environment that do not allow you to call anything outside that environment. A call through a web url away is a call outside the sandbox, requiring System.Net.WebPermissions. This is prohibited by the Code Access Security policies defined for the Sandbox.

You have 2 options here.

1. Use JavaScript Client Object Model
2. [Build a Sandbox Proxy solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798427.aspx)